# checkbox handling inside custom title of the Alert dialog in android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-alertdialog

I have an Alert Dialog in my app with custom Title and check box in the title field as shown below.[image]

When selecting an ***All*** check box, all the other items below(mutliple choice list) should be checked by default,like shown below:

[image]

Also if the ***All*** checkbox is unchecked, the previous state of selection(i.e, before selecting ***All***) should be checked and the other items should be unselected. I wanted all this to happen when the dialog is in focus.

What i tried is the below code.

```
@Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            int title = getArguments().getInt("title");


            View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.dialog_categories_title, null);

            cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < _selections.length; i++) {
                            _selections[i] = isChecked;

                        }
                    }

                }
            });

            return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setCustomTitle(view)

                    .setMultiChoiceItems(_categories, _selections,
                            new DialogSelectionClickHandler())

                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) {
                                    ((MainActivity) getActivity())
                                            .doPositiveClick();
                                }

                            }).create();
}
```

If i run this, When ***All*** is checked, the other items are checked only if i close and open the dialog again, but i want this to happen when the curren dialog is in focus. How can i do this.?

Answer (score 1):

```
    CheckBox repeatChkBx = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.repeat_checkbox);
    repeatChk2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.repeat_checkbox2);
            repeatChkBx.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        repeatChk2.setChecked(true);
                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: @altafBut how i can i get control over multiple choice list items in my app, like wat u u did here:  repeatChk2.setChecked(true);

Comment: first you get adapter if you are using listiview and run this loop end of adpater like this..  check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ @Override public void onClick(View view) {                for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++){                  Planet planet = listAdapter.getItem(i);if (planet.isChecked()) //Add this item in ArrayList Toast.makeText(context, planet.getName() + " is Checked!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}  }  }   });

Comment: I tried your method, it works. but i want the dialog to update while in focus. Your solution is working and the changes are apllicable only wen i close and reopen the dilog.

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved the thing which you are displaying in image. what i have used was Custom Dialogue. i had used Listview inside the xml file.

First of all Define initialize the below arraylist.

```
// Catagory Selection
    public static ArrayList<String> acceptpositionwhoesNearMe = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static String AcceptCatagotyIDWhoesNearMe = "";
```

Below is the Code **showDialog()** i have Used.

```
public void showDialog() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Inside Show Dialog");
        final Dialog warning = new Dialog(logout_dialogue.this);
        warning.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        warning.setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_XML);
        warning.setCancelable(false);
        warning.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        WindowManager mWinMgr;
        mWinMgr = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        int displayWidth = mWinMgr.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

        warning.getWindow().setLayout(displayWidth - 75,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        warning.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Inside Dialog interface");
                // test = true;
                warning.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ListView listinterest = (ListView) warning
                .findViewById(R.id.list_catagory);
        /*
         * ArrayList<String> count = new ArrayList<String>(); count.clear();
         * count.add("Hotels"); count.add("Restaurants"); count.add("Gardens");
         * count.add("Theater");
         */
        CatagorySummaryAdapter adapter;
        adapter = new CatagorySummaryAdapter(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this,
                YOUR_ARRAYLIST_OF_CATAGORY, true);

        listinterest.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button btnOk = (Button) warning.findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
        btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String Catagory = "";
                int count = HomeActivity.acceptpositionwhoesNearMe.size();

                if (count > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < HomeActivity.acceptpositionwhoesNearMe
                            .size(); i++) {

                        int pos = Integer
                                .parseInt(HomeActivity.acceptpositionwhoesNearMe
                                        .get(i));
                        if (Catagory.equals("")) {
                            Catagory = GetUserDetailsJsonParser.CategoryName
                                    .get(pos);
                            HomeActivity.AcceptCatagotyIDWhoesNearMe = GetUserDetailsJsonParser.CategoryID
                                    .get(pos);
                        } else {

                            Catagory = Catagory
                                    + ","
                                    + GetUserDetailsJsonParser.CategoryName
                                            .get(pos);
                            HomeActivity.AcceptCatagotyIDWhoesNearMe = HomeActivity.AcceptCatagotyIDWhoesNearMe
                                    + ","
                                    + GetUserDetailsJsonParser.CategoryID
                                            .get(pos);
                        }

                    }

                    Log.i(TAG, "Accept Catagory IDs WhoseNear Me"
                            + HomeActivity.AcceptCatagotyIDWhoesNearMe);

                    GetUserDetailsJsonParser.InterestedIn = HomeActivity.AcceptCatagotyIDWhoesNearMe;
                    UpdateMap = true;
                    /*
                     * startActivity(new Intent(WhosNearMe.this,
                     * BuildInukshk_4.class));
                     */
                    new GetUsersInRadiusAsyncTask().execute();

                    warning.dismiss();

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(WhosNearMe.this,
                            "Please Select One or More Catagory", 3).show();
                }
                // test = true;

            }
        });

        warning.show();
    }
```

Here is **My logout_dialogue.xml** :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_back_final"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <com.inukshk.CustomTextViewBold
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Interested in"
                android:textColor="#3C3C3C"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_catagory"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent" >
        </ListView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_close"
            android:layout_width="99dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_back_final"
            android:text="CLOSE"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is My **CatagorySummaryAdapter.java** :

```
package com.inukshk.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.inukshk.HomeActivity;
import com.inukshk.R;
import com.inukshk.CreateInukshk.BuildInukshk_3;
import com.inukshk.WhosNearMe.WhosNearMe;

public class CatagorySummaryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public Activity context;
    String TAG = "CatagorySummaryAdapter";
    public LayoutInflater inflater;
    public ArrayList<String> Count;
    boolean Dialogue;

    public CatagorySummaryAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> Count,
            boolean Dialogue) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        this.Count = Count;

        this.Dialogue = Dialogue;

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Count.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Count.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        RelativeLayout lsummary_row;
        TextView txtinterestname;
        CheckBox chkinterest;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int pos = position;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            if (Dialogue) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.listview_summary_dialogue_row, null);
            } else {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_summary_row,
                        null);
            }

            holder.txtinterestname = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtinterestname);
            holder.lsummary_row = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lsummary_row);
            holder.chkinterest = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.chkinterest);
            holder.chkinterest.setEnabled(true);

            holder.chkinterest.setTag(position);

            if (Dialogue) {

                for (int i = 0; i < HomeActivity.acceptpositionwhoesNearMe.size(); i++) {
                    int index = Integer
                            .parseInt(HomeActivity.acceptpositionwhoesNearMe
                                    .get(i));
                    // Log.i(TAG, "Inside for Loop of Accept Positions");
                    if (index == position) {
                        // Log.i(TAG, "Matched for index" + index);
                        holder.chkinterest.setChecked(true);
                        holder.chkinterest
                                .setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox_checked);
                    }

                }

            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < BuildInukshk_3.acceptposition.size(); i++) {
                    int index = Integer.parseInt(BuildInukshk_3.acceptposition
                            .get(i));
                    // Log.i(TAG, "Inside for Loop of Accept Positions");
                    if (index == position) {
                        // Log.i(TAG, "Matched for index" + index);
                        holder.chkinterest.setChecked(true);
                        holder.chkinterest
                                .setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox_checked);
                    }

                }
            }

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.chkinterest
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // Log.i(TAG, "ISChecked is " + isChecked);
                        if (isChecked) {
                            // Log.i(TAG, "ISChecked is true");
                            buttonView
                                    .setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox_checked);
                            int position = Integer.parseInt(buttonView.getTag()
                                    .toString());
                            if (Dialogue) {
                                HomeActivity.acceptpositionwhoesNearMe.add(String
                                        .valueOf(position));

                                Log.i(TAG, "Accept ID of Dialogue"
                                        + HomeActivity.acceptpositionwhoesNearMe);
                            } else {
                                BuildInukshk_3.acceptposition.add(String
                                        .valueOf(position));

                                Log.i(TAG, "Accept ID"
                                        + BuildInukshk_3.acceptposition);
                            }

                        } else {
                            // Log.i(TAG, "ISChecked is false");
                            buttonView
                                    .setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox_unchecked);
                            int position = Integer.parseInt(buttonView.getTag()
                                    .toString());

                            if (Dialogue) {
                                if (HomeActivity.acceptpositionwhoesNearMe
                                        .contains(String.valueOf(position))) {
                                    // Log.i(TAG,
                                    // "Inside Already present position");
                                    HomeActivity.acceptpositionwhoesNearMe
                                            .remove(String.valueOf(position));
                                    Log.i(TAG,
                                            "Accept ID Dialogue***"
                                                    + HomeActivity.acceptpositionwhoesNearMe);
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (BuildInukshk_3.acceptposition
                                        .contains(String.valueOf(position))) {
                                    // Log.i(TAG,
                                    // "Inside Already present position");
                                    BuildInukshk_3.acceptposition.remove(String
                                            .valueOf(position));
                                    Log.i(TAG, "Accept ID ***"
                                            + BuildInukshk_3.acceptposition);
                                }
                            }
                            //
                        }

                    }
                });

        holder.txtinterestname.setText(Count.get(pos));

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

try to go through it might help you.

Comment: I think you are using custom layout for your dialog, i am just using mutliple choice list in dialog and not using any xml layout. please go thru my question and need help.

Answer (score 1):

```
 ArrayList<Boolean> checked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < _selections.length; i++) {
checked.add(yourCheckBoxArray[i].isChecked)
                            _selections[i] = isChecked;

                        }
                    }
else{
for (int i = 0; i < _selections.length; i++) {
                        yourCheckBoxesArray[i].setChecked(checked.get)

                    }
                }
            });
```

when all checkbox is checked, store the values of checkboxes (true or false) in a arraylist. when user uncheck the All checkbox, then set the check boxes from the **"checkd"** arraylist

Comment: I am gettin error in this line:: catrgories[i].setChecked(checked.get)

Comment: I tried your method, it works. but i want the dialog to update while in focus. Your solution is working and the changes are applicable only wen i close and reopen the dialog

Comment: i want to update the checkbox in the current focus only, that is wen the dialog is open and if i click on "ALL" automatically other check boxes should be checked then and there itself.